# aligning a css tree of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tree structure in a nested div. Each nested div should have the same width. Example that demonstrates the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            .CssWrapper {
                width: 800px;
                overflow: scroll;
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }
            .CssTreeContainer {
                width: auto;
                display: inline;
                float: left;
                padding-left:20px;
            }
            .CssTreeValue {
                width: auto;
                float: left;
                text-align: left;
                clear: both;
            }
            .ParentLabel {
                width: auto;
                float: left;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="CssWrapper">
            <div class="CssTreeValue">
                <div class="ParentLabel">Main Node A</div>
                <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                    <div class="CssTreeValue">
                        <div class="ParentLabel">Node AA</div>
                        <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                            <div class="CssTreeValue">
                                <div class="ParentLabel">Node AAA</div>
                                <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                                    <div class="CssTreeValue">Node AAAA</div>
                                    <div class="CssTreeValue">Node AAAB</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="CssTreeValue">
                                <div class="ParentLabel">Node AAB (some extra long text)</div>
                                <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                                    <div class="CssTreeValue">Node AABA</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="CssTreeValue">Node AB</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CssTreeValue">
                <div class="ParentLabel">Main Node B</div>
                <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                    <div class="CssTreeValue">
                        <div class="ParentLabel">Node BA</div>
                        <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                            <div class="CssTreeValue">
                                <div class="ParentLabel">Node BAA</div>
                                <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                                    <div class="CssTreeValue">Node BAAA</div>
                                    <div class="CssTreeValue">Node BAAB</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="CssTreeValue">
                                <div class="ParentLabel">Node BAB</div>
                                <div class="CssTreeContainer">
                                    <div class="CssTreeValue">Node BABA</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="CssTreeValue">Node BB</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;" />
        <div id="result" />
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UptXg/

Comment: why dont you create a fiddle for this??

Comment: Unordered lists, not DIVs, should be used for this purpose.

Comment: Why don't you paste your code in a jsFiddle and demonstrate what the problem is, I don't understand your question exactly... Are you trying to make it so that all the elements in the tree are the same width? Or are you trying to make it so that they all align vertically in a specific fashion?

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd As requested by you and others there is now a jsFiddle link at http://jsfiddle.net/UptXg/ and in the original posting.

Comment: Yes I see that. I also have an answer for you, if you'd like to take the javascript/jQuery approach anyways. I really hope your tags are all balanced, on that matter, do you realize you put a `CssTreeValue` inside another `CssTreeValue`? I assume `CssTreeValue` is something that you only want to have one of it in itself. By doing that, you have a div of width 800, containing another div of width 800 inside of it. @draptik, you must consider a different approach to this problem, it's difficult to look at; I can't understand your logic.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd Thanks for taking a look. The example is just that. It is a tree. As long as the tree only has 3-4 divs, the customer will be happy...

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to specify a width for all of your nested divs, like so:

```
.CssWrapper div {
    width: 800px;
}
```

Also, remove the display:inline, and overflow;scroll, unless you want scrollbars all over the place.

Comment: What do you mean it will not live up to it? The Css style sheet should also work for any created elements in the document with the specified class. Unless you're changing classes on the fly, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you gave me...

```
$('.CssWrapper').find('div').css({width: 800px});
```

This will find the elements with the class `CssWrapper` and search through all the descendants to find `div`'s. Then it will set all their width's to 800px

Also MoonKat1216's answer works. He's using a Css selector to get the div descendants of the `.CssWrapper` class; which is better practice because it goes in your css style sheet and it's more organized than doing it in javascript like I have here because you can more easily edit your css styles, instead of searching through javascript code. However, if you are doing this on the fly, and changing the value or classes etc. This would be the way to go. It's really dependent on your situation.